# How to convert LatLng to address Flutter (both iOS and Android version)

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation, geocoding, geocoder

I am creating an app with Flutter that uses [geocoding plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/geocoding) in order to convert LatLng position to address.

Here my code:

```
import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  late String location = "location name";

  Future<String> getAddress() async {
    List<Placemark> placemarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
        45.478981,9.207120,
        localeIdentifier: 'it_It');
    return placemarks[0].name.toString();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Convert LatLng to Address")),
        body: Center(
          child: Stack(children: [
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(location),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    getAddress().then((value) => {
                          setState(() {
                            location = value;
                          }),
                          print(value)
                        });
                  },
                  child: const Text('Convert LatLng'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ]),
        ));
  }
}
```

The result of the conversion is different between iOS and Android version, for example:

```
LatLng = 45.478981,9.207120
```

**iOS version result:** *"Via Alessandro Tadino 21"*

**Android version result:** *"46"*

I don't understand why it is different, should I use another plugin?
Perhaps the plugin uses two different technologies for iOS and Android. Does Android use a sort of Google Maps plugin?

Comment: Have you followed the installation guide mentioned here: https://pub.dev/packages/geocoding#usage (it's for android)

Comment: @Martin Yes I have, except the third point, which I did not understand

Comment: Well, the android result is wrong 100%. If nothing else works try on an emulator which has play services installed or an actual physical device if you have one.

Comment: @Martin thanks, I used Android emulator from Android Studio

Comment: right, so make sure it has google play services. You can check that in the AVD manager when creating an emulator.

Comment: @Martin unfortunately I checked, it has Google Play services, but it is still not working :(

Comment: @Martin actually I figured out that it returns the right addresses if the locations are from the USA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is reverse geocoding

> Reverse geocoding is the process of converting geographic coordinates into a human-readable address.

Since you need exact same outputs on both android and iOS devices, I'd suggest you use [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview)

Then you can use the API key with [google_geocoding](https://pub.dev/packages/google_geocoding) package and get places using coordinates

```dart
var googleGeocoding = GoogleGeocoding("API-KEY");
var result = await googleGeocoding.geocoding.getReverse(LatLon(40.714224,-73.961452));
```